# How can I start the iPad Photoframe Mode / Slideshow for a given Playlist name

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is there an API to start a slideshow for a given playlist?

Say I have prepared 2 playlists, one containing pictures, the other one movies - and I like to start the stock photo application / photo frame / movie player to play the contents of these playlists.

Is that possible?

Additionally, is it also possible to retrieve all playlists in the iPod module (for the user to select them in a settings screen)?

Pointers to the right direction are also welcome. :-) thx

Comment: I just found Three20 and the appropriate fork for iPad. I think it's a little bit too sophisticated for me. Just default values & playback would be enough. One picture at a time though.

Comment: And there I found the MediaPlayer framework. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006952 and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765  - so looks like I'm on the right track.

Comment: MediaPlayer framework cannot query Videos or users Photos it seems..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this using `UIScrollView` and `NSTimer` to create the effect.

There are plenty of tutorials on Google how to do this. Someone can comment if sample code is needed, as I can't remember the sources..